# @RabbitListener how to set frequency of receiving messages in annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using @RabbitListner annotation to recieve messages from a RabbitMq queue.
How to make threads receive messages no more often than 1 second?

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "message", priority = "3",concurrency = "2")
public void receiveCheck(RequestMessage message){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is a bit strange. Don't you think that the problem should be solved differently (maybe you can send messages with a certain frequency - 1 message/sec)?
But if you're sure that's what you need, you could use primitive solution:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "message", priority = "3", concurrency = "2")
public void receiveMessage(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">" + " Message time: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Or with the calculation of the operation time:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "message", priority = "3", concurrency = "2")
public void receiveMessageWithTimer(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">" + " Message time: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long operationTime = finish - start;
    Thread.sleep(1000 - operationTime);
}
```

But in this case you should remeber that concurrency level = 2. And you will receive 2 message/sec.
For receiving of only one message you could set concurrency level = 1.